# Field of algebraic reals over the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

> Let $L = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x \text{ is algebraic over } \mathbb{Q} \}$ be the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting by all reals that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K$ be finite field extension of $L$ such that $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. By the primitive element theorem $K = L(a)$. Denote by $f(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L$. Prove $f(x)$ has no real roots.

Any hints ?

Comment: I don't think you can use the PET for the reason Benja mentioned. Perhaps you want to talk about an algebraic element $\,a\in K-L\,$?

Comment: Anyway, I think the result is true for any algebraic element $a\in K-L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\,K/L\,$ is a finite *non-trivial* extension ( $\,K\neq L\,$) then clearly $\,a\in\Bbb C-\Bbb R\,$ .

If the minimal polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ of $\,a\,$ over $\,L\,$ had a real root $\,w\,$ then 
$$\,L(w)/L\,,\,L/\Bbb Q\,\,\text{are both algebraic}\, \,\Longrightarrow L(w)/\Bbb Q\,\,\text{is algebraic}$$  and thus $\,w\in L\Longrightarrow\,(x-w)\mid f(x)\,$ in $\,L[x]\,\Longrightarrow a\,$ is a root of 
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x-w}\in L[x]\,\,\,and\,\,\,\deg\frac{f(x)}{x-w}<\deg f(x)$$
which of course cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

The only algebraic extensions of $L$ are $L$ itself (which is a real closed field) and $ L(i) = \overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ (which is an algebraically closed field).